# google recaptcha not display in comment form

Tags: wordpress

I have installed and activated the plugin, got the site and secret keys by registering the domain but the recaptcha is not displaying with the comment form. can you suggest something please?

Comment: which plugin you installed ??

Comment: Google Captcha (reCAPTCHA) by BestWebSoft

Comment: if there any error showing ? could you please share your link ??

Comment: http://fouaddba.com/agent-is-down/

Comment: That plugin is not compatible with contact from 7 please check this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/dont-work-for-contact-form-7/

Comment: suggest me other reCaptcha plugin ?

Comment: You can try this one https://contactform7.com/recaptcha/

Comment: but i want add recaptcha in comment form...how to i add recaptcha in comment form?

Comment: are you using default comment form or  Jetpack comments form. ?

Comment: Did you enabled captcha for comment form in settings?https://ps.w.org/google-captcha/trunk/screenshot-8.png?rev=1842706

Comment: im using default comment form.

Comment: Then you didnt activated the captcha for comment form that may be issue

Comment: any other option?

Comment: You can ask plugin support

Comment: how to add recaptcha in Jetpack comments form?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/